# Error with multiple Bazel BUILD files: "Target 'bar' is not visible from target 'foo'"

Tags: bazel

My project as the following structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── bar.cpp
│   └── BUILD
├── BUILD
├── foo.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

Content of `./BUILD`:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [ "foo.cpp" ],
    deps = [ "//bar" ],
)
```

Content of `bar/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "bar",
    srcs = ["bar.cpp"],
)
```

If I build `foo`, I get the following error:

```
Target '//bar:bar' is not visible from target '//:foo'. Check the visibility declaration of the former target if you think the dependency is legitimate.
```

What do I need to do so the dependency can be resolved and `foo` is built successfully?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Bazel docs](http://bazel.io/docs/getting-started.html):

> However, by default, build rules are private. This means that they can only be referred to by rules in the same BUILD file.
>   [...]
>   You can make a rule visibile to rules in other BUILD files by adding a `visibility = level` attribute.

In this case, `bar/BUILD` should look as follows:

```
cc_library(
    name = "bar",
    srcs = ["bar.cpp"],
    visibility = ["//__pkg__"],
)
```

The additional line `visibility = ["//__pkg__"]` allows all `BUILD` files in the current WORKSPACE to access the target `bar`.

Answer (score 11):

`visibility = ["//__pkg__"]` didn't work for me.
But I've managed to make it work by adding

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
```

as the first line of the `bar/BUILD` file.